# Need help on efficiency in raphael

Tags: arrays, loops, raphael, mouseover

At the moment I'm starting to pick up javascript, and I'm having a problem with raphael(and probably a general JavaScript problem). I need to make my code more compact, but I don't know how. I already put everything in an array, but I don't know how I can make the hover-events more compact.

here's the code.

```
window.onload = function() {
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('holder'), 500, 500);

var rect1 = paper.rect(50,300,75,75).attr({fill:'#F00'});
var rect2 = paper.rect(50,200,75,75).attr({fill:'#0F0'});
var rect3 = paper.rect(50,100,75,75).attr({fill:'#00F'});
var rect4 = paper.rect(150,100,75,75).attr({fill:'#FF0'});
var rect5 = paper.rect(150,200,75,75).attr({fill:'#F0F'});
var rect6 = paper.rect(150,300,75,75).attr({fill:'#000'});
var rect7 = paper.rect(250,100,75,75).attr({fill:'#0FF'});
var rect8 = paper.rect(250,200,75,75).attr({fill:'#F04'});
var rect9 = paper.rect(250,300,75,75).attr({fill:'#079'});

var Objects;
Objects.push(rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5, rect6, rect7, rect8, rect9);

rect1.mouseover(function(){
rect1.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect1.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect2.mouseover(function(){
rect2.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect2.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect3.mouseover(function(){
rect3.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect3.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect4.mouseover(function(){
rect4.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect4.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect5.mouseover(function(){
rect5.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect5.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect6.mouseover(function(){
rect6.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect6.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect7.mouseover(function(){
rect7.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect7.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect8.mouseover(function(){
rect8.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect8.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
    rect9.mouseover(function(){
rect9.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', function(){ rect9.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce');});
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use something like a set, and have a custom function which uses the 'this' element inside it, which refers to the object itself thats being used. Using a set or Array, you can then iterate over them easily.

```
var Objects = paper.set();
Objects.push(rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5, rect6, rect7, rect8, rect9);

function rectAnimOver() {
    this.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'bounce')
};

function rectAnim() {
    this.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000, 'bounce', rectAnimOver)
};

Objects.forEach( function( el ) {
    el.mouseover( rectAnim );
} );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqhhtkjs/1/)